# get distinct date only with id (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to get the distinct dates along with its ID on table shopping_t and I already tried using **distinct** but for some reason it gives me an error

```
SELECT 
guest_id,  shopping_date
FROM
shopping_t
WHERE
(shopping_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND NOW())
order by
guest_id
```

the code above gives me

```
0   2016-01-02
0   2016-01-03
0   2016-01-05
0   2016-01-02 <-- result that I don't need
1   2016-01-02
1   2016-01-03
1   2016-01-08
1   2016-03-08
2   2016-01-02
2   2016-01-03
2   2016-01-08
2   2016-03-08
```

my desired ouput is

```
0   2016-01-02
0   2016-01-03
0   2016-01-05
1   2016-01-02
1   2016-01-03
1   2016-01-08
1   2016-03-08
2   2016-01-02
2   2016-01-03
2   2016-01-08
2   2016-03-08
```

I've tried using distinct but I don't know why it gives me an error

```
SELECT 
guest_id, distinct(shopping_date)
FROM
shopping_t
WHERE
(shopping_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND NOW())
order by
guest_id
```

I've been looking for solution for almost an hour

Comment: Knowing what you want and what you get is great. But knowing what you start with is nice too.

Answer (score 0):

`distinct` is not a function.  `distinct` is modifier on `select`.  So, try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT guest_id, shopping_date
FROMshopping_t
WHERE (shopping_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND NOW())
ORDER BY guest_id;
```

This assumes that `shopping_date` has not time component.  If it does have a time component, then extract the date, say by using the `date()` function:

```
SELECT DISTINCT guest_id, DATE(shopping_date) as shopping_date
FROMshopping_t
WHERE shopping_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND NOW()
ORDER BY guest_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT guest_id, shopping_date
FROM shopping_t
WHERE (shopping_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH AND NOW())
group by shopping_date,guest_id
ORDER BY guest_id;
```